# calling const member function

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

i have called const member function of an object.

I created an object on MainWindow, den called get_size() after setting size previously.

calling get_size() method of base class Gtk::Window.

It gives error: ‘Gtk::Window’ is not an accessible base of ‘MainWindow’.

MainWindow is inherited from Gtk::Window class

```
class MainWindow: Gtk::Window
{

};
```

What could be the reason for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inhertance is `private` by default for classes.  You need to derive from `Gtk::Window` publicly:

```
class MainWindow: public Gtk::Window {
```

Comment: Actually I'm surprised he didn't get a compile error at class MainWindow: Gtk::Window, I thought you always had to specify the access type.

Comment: @saluton: nope, he could've write `struct MainWindow: Gtk::Window` and inheritance would be `public`, because it's default for `struct` s.

Answer (score 3):

should probably be:

```
class MainWindow: public Gtk::Window
{

};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit with `private` word (and that's how you inherit when you don't specify any word for `class`) every method from `Gtk::Window` become private in `MainWindow` (even if it's declared as `public` or `protected` in `Gtk::Window`).

If you inherit with `protected` word every `public` methods from base class become `protected` methods in inherited class. `private` methods stay as they are.

`public` inheritance doesn't change anything. It's default inheritance for class declared with `struct` keyword.

It seems you forgot to use `public` in class declaration.